# Matlabe ODE45 Error How to store Variables

Tags: matlab, ode

The eqns I am solving: 
[image: equations]

[Updated Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5yxJ15gF)

I have provided initial conditions to my variables, but they are not differential equations.  Is it ok to add them to my vector of DE's?

The (latest) error message is: FUN1_ORIG returns a vector of length 14, but the length of the initial conditions vector is 21. [they must have the same number of elements].

Where can I place if statements to check conditions after every step/increment?

Comment: in the first line in the function, you are accessing `y(15)` while `y` has only 14 elements.

Comment: How should I otherwise define/store them? Can I add this matrix, z to store them?                                                                                       function [yprime,z] = funfile(t,y)

Comment: In the script you have initialized `yprime=zeros(14,1);` to be the function's second input. However in the first line of the function `yprime(16)` is demanded. If you meant all initial values are zero then you can initialize `yprime` to a bigger vector.

Comment: They are just variables, not derivatives, so I don't think I want to do that.  [See here](https://imgur.com/a/ggyNA) These are when I need to calculate and retrieve C1,C2,Pa,Mw,Mn,Y,Z

Comment: So you have created a dependency loop. `y(1)` depends on `y(15)` which depends on `y(9)` which depends on `y(1)`.

Comment: Ok Do I need anonymous function or wrapper? or nested function? Thx

Comment: This is not a matter of Matlab code itself, but more related to algorithm. You cannot assign a variable that depends on its future value after this assignment, unless give an initial value (like 0) at the beginning.

Comment: Ok. I'll set them to zero at the beginning.  Now I get this error: "subscript indices must be either positive integers.    "

Comment: That means you have things like `y(0)` or `y(-1)`. Please update your code.

Comment: I updated my code and the error.  Next, I am going to try storing my variables in my vector of DE's to make the dimensions equal, but I don't want those variables to be treated like differential equations by ODE45.

Answer (score 0):

The following method works for me. What I can understand from your code is that you need some temporary values when evaluating `funfile` that should not survive after the calculation. Besides the fact that it is better to store the unwanted temporary things in a separate place, you can expand the `y` vector before the calculation, and then trim it after finishing.

```
function yprime = testf(t,y)
global MR
global y2

y(21) = 0;
%We have 14 differential equations, using these indices
%yprime=[A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O]
%        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1011121314
.... (some 50 lines untouched)

%Z
y(20)=y(17)*(3/2);

%Y
y(21)=(106+(15/y(20))*(y(10)+y(11)+y(12)+2*(y(13)+y(14))))...
    /(1-(y(5)+y(6)+y(13)+y(14)+3*y(7))/y(20));

y2 = y(15:21);
yprime=transpose(yprime);
end
```

while in the script, still define `yprime=zeros(14,1);` and also define a global variable to store the expanded data.

```
yprime=zeros(14,1);
global y2
y2 = zeros(7,1);
yprime(1)=1;%A_0
```

Complex numbers are expected since you have imaginary numbers involved in the assignments. This is not a programming issue.

Comment: Actually, they are not "unwanted temporary things."  I need to plot them too.

Comment: I got it to run, but I have complex numbers, which I assume I just want the real part.  However, one number I cannot calculate "Not a number," because of this

Comment: It was not able to integrate for long enough, so I need to use a stiff integrator, but ODE15s refuses because "I have a singular or badly scaled matrix".